# How to read from the stdin with nim script?

Tags: nim-lang

How would i read from the stdin via nimscript?

**i've tried:**

```
if readLine(stdin) == "yes":
  exec buildCommand
```

**i've run the script with**

```
nim c build.nims
```

**i receive**

> build.nims(50, 13) Error: undeclared identifier: 'stdin'

Answer (score 4):

I don't think nimscript supports reading from `stdin` just yet.

You might want to create a feature request for this: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues

Answer (score 2):

```
var f : File;
discard f.open(0, fmRead)

let s = f.readLine()
echo "INPUT " & s
```

... works -- stdin has file handle 0

Comment: gives me `foo.nims(2, 10) Error: attempting to call undeclared routine: 'open'`

i'm on `Version 0.13.0`

Comment: hmm ... I'm using that version too. For me it resolves to http://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#open,File,FileHandle,FileMode (FileHandle is just cint)

Answer (score 2):

This is now implemented in nimscript in devel: [`readAllFromStdin()`](https://nim-lang.github.io/Nim/nimscript.html#readAllFromStdin).

It will be available in Nim v0.20.0+ (yet to be released as of 2019-05-21).